# how to do active active load balacing in strongswan?

Tags: load-balancing, ipsec, strongswan

I want to load balance my IPsec tunnel data I've got two wan lines in company A and one wan line in company b. I want to load balance my data packet in company A. does anybody have a configuration sample file of strongswan for explanation

Comment: Have you looked at StrongSwan's official wiki? https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/HighAvailability comes to mind...

Comment: I don't have a firewall cluster in company A but a single firewall with two wan lines. I want  my IPSec data to travel from both of the wan lines

Comment: Arf you setting up StrongSwan on the firewall or another server?

Comment: on the firewall